# How to set up a time out for a robocopy command in batch?

Tags: windows, batch-file, scripting, batch-processing

I'm struggling to set a time out to a **robocopy** batch. After a while it should exit the **robocopy** command even it's not ended.

```
for /f %%i IN (servers.txt) DO (
    rem insert the counter of time out
    robocopy C:\test \\%%i\C$\test /S
)
```

Sometimes **robocopy** freezes on one server.

Comment: so you want to timeout the script if robocopy freezes and exit?

Comment: Are you looking for [\[SS64\]: `set /p`](https://ss64.com/nt/set.html)?

Comment: Perhaps you are interested in the `/R` and `/W` options of `robocopy`...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this? you will need another cmd file. This one will call the other file which we will call robo_start.cmd

```
start rbo_start.cmd
timeout 300
taskkill /im robo_start.cmd /F
```

then robo_start.cmd will be your original file.

```
for /f %%i IN (servers.txt) DO 

  ( 
    robocopy C:\test \%%i\C$\test /S
  )
```

Windows cmd does not have a function to exit if something takes too long, so you have to butcher it a bit.

probably a more robust method would be to just set the retry count on robocopy. The default retry count is 1 Million and you can set it to something that makes more realistic.

```
for /f %%i IN (servers.txt) DO 
( 
robocopy /R:1 C:\test \%%i\C$\test /S
)
```